# Squid use eth1 outgoing ip change

Tags: squid

I've set up squid as an http proxy and I've multi nic cards, by default it uses eth1 ip for outgoing; I want it to use eth1:1 ip for outgoing. Any clue?

Answer (score 4):

Correct option is `tcp_outgoing_address`.

```
tcp_outgoing_address 123.123.123.123
```

Of course, replace 123.123.123.123 with your ip address assigned to eth1:1

Answer (score 0):

Squid allows you to give it an explicit IP and port combination to bind to. If that IP is bound to eth1:1, that's what it'll use for inbound connections.

```
http_port 192.168.1.32:3128
```

To specify which address it'll use for *outbound* connections, the `tcp_outgoing_address` directive is a club used to force all traffic to come FROM a specific port.

```
tcp_outgoing_address 192.168.1.32
```

Answer (score -2):

man squid.conf

http_port ip_adderss:port

Comment: http_port options sets where squid will listen for incoming requests, not which ip address it will use for outgoing connections